# Performance comparison of two sql statements in TDengine

Tags: query-performance, tdengine

I have two sql statements in TDengine database:

```
select count(*)  from  gps_info where pos_time>='2022-11-04 00:00:00' and pos_time<='2022-11-04 23:59:59' and device_hash='1125' ;

select count(*)  from (select device_id,pos_time,device_hash from gps_info where pos_time>='2022-11-04 00:00:00' and pos_time<='2022-11-04 23:59:59') a where device_hash='1125'
```

The first statement takes less than 1 second,but the second statement takes 35 seconds.

The result of these two statements is the same, so why is the performance difference so big?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know TDEngine specifically, but the second query has a subquery, and in most database systems the subquery would possibly be processed first before the outer query's filters are applied. This would depend on how the table is indexed, and how that database system's engine works in particular around when it finds it more efficient to seek on one index vs scanning the clustered index. It also probably depends on other factors of how that database system's engine is designed. I would bet that's probably what's happening here.

That means in your first query, it immediately filters the data down by `device_hash='1125'` but in the second query it has to return all rows of all `device_hash`es (within your date range) first, and then subsequently filters by `device_hash='1125'` after.

Comment: "*and in most database systems the subquery would likely be processed first*" - I disagree. In most modern DBMS both queries would result in exactly the same execution plan. A derived table like that is typically merged into one single query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well one difference between both queries is the second one is `SELECT`ing fields that aren't even referenced in the first one (`device_id`), so it's hard for me to believe both would always result in exactly the same plan. Surely there are other unknown factors that could result in if the two queries yield the same plan or not, such as how the table is indexed.

Comment: The columns in the SELECT list of the derived table are never used and the final query only uses `count(*)` The WHERE conditions are identical, so I am pretty certain this would lead to identical execution plans.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, because the outer query is not dependent on the other columns and because it only cares about the count of rows, in a lot of database systems they would likely generate the same plan because the second query would essentially ignore the `SELECT` list of the inner query in a short-circuited kind of way. But not all systems, for all circumstances, and I'm not sure about for a timescale database like TDEngine. I did misspeak a little in my original Post though, and have corrected that.